what does "auto(*)" mean in "auto(*)(int, int)->bool"?
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    priority_queue< int, vector<int>, auto(*)(int, int)->bool > que1;
    priority_queue< int, vector<int>, function<bool(int, int)>> que2;
    return 0;
}

These two line of priority_queue initialization both works, but I have a hard time wrapping my head around what auto(*) means.
I do know (int, int)->bool means a function with two int arguments and returns a bool value.
What does auto(*) mean? How does it work?

auto(*)(int, int)->bool means it is a pointer to a function taking two ints as argument and returning a bool. It's called trailing return type syntax. See Arrow operator (->) in function heading which should clear your doubts.

Basically same as(or fancy way of writing) bool(*)(int, int)

(int, int)->bool doesn't mean anything without the auto in front. The syntax is return_type (args, args) or auto (arg, args) -> return_type. If you want to use the -> then you have to put auto in front.

Also Using a function pointer with a trailing return type

The auto, in this case, means this is a function pointer with a trailing return type, after the ->.   So auto (*)(int, int) -> bool is functionally equivalent to bool (*)(int, int)  i.e. a pointer to a function that accepts two arguments of type int and returns a bool.

@Peter so * implies that it's a function pointer , but why does the asterisk appear in the middle of the expression ? I thought it shoud be something like * (bool(int,int)) ? but * (bool(int,int))  dosen't work . bool(*)(int,int) does work .

@iouvxz Note also the normal functions decay to function pointers in many contexts.

"why does the asterisk appear in the middle..." Because it's the syntax to declare a function pointer. See Explanation of function pointers which explains this. Also a good c++ book.

@user12002570 Now I get it ,I shall read up on Pointers to functions .

@iouvxz, It comes from C declaration syntax, which mimics use. If you do (*fptr)(some_int, some_int), the result is a bool, so fptr is a pointer to a function taking an int and an int and returning bool.
